# How to refresh rails application after modify some file which deployed by Nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

Deployed a rails application using Nginx and Unicorn. Want to change config file. Is it necessary to restart Nginx? Or just do `touch public/robots.txt`?

If it works, why do `touch public/robots.txt` but not trigger at other files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `touch tmp/restart.txt` method is passenger specific. With unicorn, you can send a `USR2` signal to it from the directory of the updated code to kill it, and restart the Unicorn instance.

Depending on the OS you're running it in, sending the signal could be different (`sig` vs `kill` etc). Also assuming you use Capistrano for deployment:

```
# Kill unicorn
run "kill -s USR2 `cat #{unicorn_pid_file_location}`"

# then restart unicorn with updated config
run "#{unicorn_rails_or_unicorn} -c #{your_current_folder}/config/unicorn.rb -D -E production"
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems like should restart unicorn, but not nginx. The changing of rails is must to kill old unicorn pid?

Comment: Yeah you shouldn't need to restart nginx